# Functional Analysis book with graphical descriptions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for some book about functional analysis that has also graphical descriptions and images of the important concepts.

Anyone knows some book like this?

Comment: Just an idea: look at https://sanjindumisic.com/artwork-by-anatoly-fomenko/

Comment: How do you propose to have a graphical description of weakly compact non-compact subsets? What are you actually hoping for here?